# Get a list of messages sent by IoT device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am looking for a way to see which device has sent which message in Azure.
Via "IoT-hub" we can get a list of the devices but I cannot seem to find a way to correlate the messages to the devices.

Doe anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a message arrives in IoT Hub, the hub adds a number of system properties to the message, including the *deviceid* of the device that sent the message - for more information about message properties, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct

If you're using C# to read the messages, see the **ConnectionDeviceId** property of this class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.messagesystempropertynames?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct) document for more details about the message format. 
The device id is a part of the IoT Hub message system properties such as *ConnectionDeviceId*.

The following example shows a query of the ASA job. You can see how to get the device id from the telemetry message via the stream pipeline:

```
WITH subquery as (
  SELECT 
    System.Timestamp as time,
    counter,
    temperature, 
    humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId as deviceId,
    IoTHub.MessageId as messageId
  FROM iot Timestamp by time
)

SELECT
    *
INTO
    outBlob
FROM
    subquery
```

another example is for Azure EventHubTrigger Function (AF). The telemetry message from the stream pipeline (events endpoint) is serialized into the EventData object and pushed to the AF:

```
  public static async Task Run(EventData ed, TraceWriter log)
  {  
     log.Info($"Label = {ed.SystemProperties["iothub-message-source"]} -{ed.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]}/{ed.SequenceNumber}");

     // ...
  }
```

Comment: hey roman, what is the iot collection that you query against ? the documentation only seems to be mentioning devices and devices.jobs collections .. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language

Comment: @sakthig the above query is for Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) job, see more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs