# Can not find Device Id in Azure IoTHub events

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to use Azure IoTHub to receive some sensor data. I manage to receive the messages from devices using [`EventProcessorClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092129/how-to-realtime-listen-and-consume-messages-from-azure-iot-hub). But, my problem is that I have lots of devices and I want to know which one is sending the message. I can't find it in `ProcessEventArgs` properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444549/get-a-list-of-messages-sent-by-iot-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct). The device id is in system properties:`{eventArgs}.Data.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]`

Also, you can find some other properties.